# Extract debug information in separate file with Visual C++

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-c++

I would like to extract the debug information from my binary and store it into a separate file in case I need to debug it later.

Using the gcc toolchain I would proceed as follow:

```
objcopy --only-keep-debug foo foo.debug     # extract debug info to food.debug
stripg -g foo                               # clean binary
objcopy --add-gnu-debug-link=foo.debug foo  # add .gnu_debuglink section
```

Is there any equivalent on Visual C++? I read about [How to: Debug a Release Build](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/fsk896zz.aspx) but this is not what I want since I must deliver the final version without any kind of debug information.

Comment: Which version of VC++ might be relevant here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual C++ stores its debug information in separate files already ([the `.pdb` files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd4f8bd1%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)).

Comment: Even there is a separated .pdb file, the binary file (ex. a .dll file) in debug version is much larger (sometimes > 2x in size ) than that in release version. Is it only because of those optimization options?

Comment: @gzh Yes, optimization can make generated code smaller. Or larger, but more often smaller.